# SwiftUI: VStack ignoring wrapping ZStack frame

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm currently working on a rather simple view: a bunch of `H/VStacks` on top of each other using a `ZStack`.
I'm constraining the size of my `ZStack` using the `.frame` modifier. For some reason my nested `VStack` seems to ignore its parent frame.
What I want to achieve is that the `VStack` matches the frame of the `ZStack` in the same way that the `Image` does.

```
struct CourseTileView: View {
    let viewModel: CourseTileViewModel
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Image(uiImage: viewModel.thumbnail)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFill()
                .clipped()
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    HStack {
                        ForEach(viewModel.mediaTypes.sorted(), id: \.self) {
                            $0.image
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                        }
                    }
                    Spacer()
                    RedCapsuleTextView(title: "NEW")
                        .isHidden(!viewModel.isBadgeVisible)
                }
                Spacer()
                Text(viewModel.title)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.mpText.bold())
                ProgressBar(
                    tintColor: .white,
                    backgroundColor: .white.alpha(0.3),
                    progress: viewModel.progress
                )
                .frame(width: 144, height: 7)
                .isHidden(viewModel.progress == .zero)
            }
            .padding()
        }
        .frame(width: 164, height: 270)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
    }
}
```

The blue border is the size of the `VStack` reported in the preview:
[image]

Is it necessary to set a frame for the `VStack` as well?

### Update

Using a GeometryReader would solve the problem, but... is that the way to go?

```
ZStack {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Image(uiImage: viewModel.thumbnail)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .clipped()
        VStack {
            // Content
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: geometry.size.width)
        .padding(.horizontal, Margin.small)
        .padding(.vertical, Margin.medium)
    }
    .frame(width: 164, height: 270)
    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
}
```

Comment: you want your Image and your content aka VStack respect to frame of (164X270) or what? which of those three things are the base for you? frame or Image or VStack?

Comment: I want the ZStack to be the base, therefore I'm setting the frame there. Every child view should respect ZStack's frame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might need to use [`overlay`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/overlay(_:alignment:)) instead of a `ZStack`. This forces the overlaying view (your `VStack`) to constrain to the bottom view (your `Image`). Here's a simplified version of your code:

```
struct CourseTileViewModel {
    var title = "How to deal with stack overflow questions"
    var thumbnail = UIImage(named: "Image")!
}
struct ContentView21: View {
    let viewModel = CourseTileViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: viewModel.thumbnail)
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
            .clipped()
            .frame(width: 164, height: 270)
            .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10))
            
            /// overlay will be the exact same size as the image
            .overlay(
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text(viewModel.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity) /// make it take up as much width as possible
                .padding()
                .border(Color.blue)
            )
            
    }
}
```

Result:

<kbd>[image: Overlaying text does not get cut off]</kbd>